# Graph API: Strange behaviour

Tags: php, json, api, graph

For a certain project, I need to be able to specifically identify users that have posted comments on a certain group in FB. For that I'm using Graph API, so far, so good.

But here's the thing, when querying directly in my browser using a URL such as this one :
**graph.facebook.com/{mygroupID}/feed?limit=20&access_token={myAccessToken}**

And when performing the same query in the Graph Explorer, I get different results, and specifically, the IDs of the posting users are different, here, when querying info about a specific comment, I get this:

**Browser Query**
[http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/1GivwP.png http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/1GivwP.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/1GivwP.png)

**And now, when using Graph API :**
[http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/2cGO2p.png http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/2cGO2p.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/12/22/2cGO2p.png)

There, Two different user IDs for the same user and comment : **578959972247831 --> 578954092248419**
How is this even possible? And how can I fix this?

By the way, the second one (the one I get on Graph Explorer) is the correct one, the first points simply nowhere.

Thank you.

Comment: I've edited those images into the question for clarity.

Comment: Looks like the ID in 'from' could be "A profile can be a User, a Page, a Group, an Event." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/profile - is it possible that your browser request includes some of your actual facebook authentication and the value of that field changes based on your permissions? Maybe try making the non graph-api request in an incognito window (Cmd+shift+n).

Comment: ArfOfCode Thank you.
@pherris Tried incognito, same result so far. Also with a different FB Account.

Comment: @Unforgiven, could you please describe how you post using `https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?access_token={page_token}&message=This is`. I am able to get page's token, however when I run a query to post some text, I simply get all records from feed and nothing is being posted. Thank you.

Comment: @RustamUmarov Unfortunately, all i've ever tried to do was querying data, not posting (it was for some sort of research project). And in all honesty, I'm not even sure the API hasn't changed since then. Sorry I could'nt be of much help. You should start your own question, perhaps you'll have better luck.